# No data found when access the website

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

> I had strange issue as when I worked at my website which i use **Magento ver. 1.6.2.0** CMS and when I click on **product page** i am not find the product data it was blank page .so what happened I don't how to solve it.I tried to solve this issue but I couldn't.I hope if some one help me .

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough info to get help. You need to troubleshoot your system by looking into the logs.

"Mostly while working with Magento, you end up with serious errors or broken stuffs. So, Magento Error Logs come to the rescue here. Whenever you have a serious error on your site, you can just view your error logs and debug the error and get rid of that situation. As simple as it is. Many of you may be wondering, how to switch on Magento Error Logs or view it. So,here are the simple steps : 1) Turn on your logging: Admin > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes 2) Watch your var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log for raw information from this. You may run into file permission errors, so you might need to set your folder permissions appropriately. Source : http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento - See more at: http://magentoexpert.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-view-magento-error-logs.html#sthash.qPwoM5fo.dpuf"
(source: http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-error-logs/#)